# Drill down in Splunk 6

Tags: splunk

I'm new to building dashboards in splunk and trying to add a drilldown that shows the raw logs for the query but when you click on the desired field it shows the events for time based on the date&time picker instead of the specific time the event occured. How do I fix the issue to have the raw logs show for the specific time and event the user clicks on instead of all the events based on the date&time picker?